# Binomial theorem corollary puzzling, shouldn't $(-1)^k 1^{n-k}$ be $(-1)^{n-k}(1)^k$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

According to the binomoial theorm 
$$(x+y)^{n} = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{n}{j}x^{n-j}y^{j}=\binom{n}{0}x^{n}+\binom{n}{1}x^{n-1}y + 
... + \binom{n}{n-1}x y^{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}y^n$$

but my textbook says
$$0=0^{n}=((-1)+1)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}1^{k}$$

shouldn't  $$(-1)^{k} 1^{n-k}$$ be $$(-1)^{n-k}1^{k}$$?

Since different k would determine different signs, namely + or -. 
Please fill me in. thanks.

Comment: I think there's a typo in the formula, one $n$ should be over the sigma, but appears to multiply $\binom{n}{k}$.  I think there's a second typo where you've already switched $(-1)^k1^{n-k}$ with $(-1)^{n-k}1^k$.  To answer what I think the actual question is, note that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* The representation is valid, since
\begin{align*}
(x+y)^n=(y+x)^n
\end{align*}